# Javascript fadein fadeout not working

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and cant seem to get it right, I had it fading in but not out, and now that I have it setup to fadein and out it doesnt work at all.  What am I missing

javascript:

```
function fadein(objectID, amount) {
    object = document.getElementById(objectID);

    animatefadein = function() {
        var MIN_OPACITY = 0;
        var MAX_OPACITY = 1;
        if (object.style.opacity < MAX_OPACITY && object.style.opacity > MIN_OPACITY) {
            var current = Number(object.style.opacity);
            var newopac = current + amount;
            object.style.opacity = String(newopac);
            setTimeout('animatefadein()', 25);
        }
    }
    animatefadein();
}
```

and the html

```
<div id="rolloverwrapper" style="opacity:0;"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="button">
            <img src="images/dj.png" onmouseover="fadein('rolloverwrapper', 0.1);" onmouseout="fadein('rolloverwrapper', -0.1);"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe any css field is converted into a string when it's added to an element's `style` object. You'll need to call `parseFloat()` on the field in order to get it's numeric value.

Comment: as opposed to `Number(object.style.opacity)`?

Comment: When I did a fade-in/fade-out, I used to pass the current value to the function in the timeout. I have two examples working: [link](http://wforums.net/project/) and [link](http://schrijnwerkerij-de-jonghe.be/Home.html)

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau The `if` block's check doesn't convert the value. Looks like you figured it out already anyway. Also, IMO, fade effects (as well as other visual effects) are best done with CSS3 (4 lines of css vs 40kb of JQuery), but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? The terrific [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library will do that for you (not to mention many other neat transitions).

```
$("#button").fadeOut(500, function() { console.log("done"); });
```

will fade the "button" div out for 500 ms, and log "done" after it's finished.

Comment: But I dont want to fade the button div out, I want to fade the rolloverwrapper in and out when the mouse rolls over a completely different div

Comment: If you're looking at mouse events - use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout. The latter don't bubble down and probably won't give you the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Art Hanzel's answer, you should use jQuery with this. But, in order to solve your problem, change your function as below (the if condition was not right in your version):

```
function fadein(objectID, amount) {
    object = document.getElementById(objectID);
    animatefadein = function() {
        var MIN_OPACITY = 0;
        var MAX_OPACITY = 1;
        if ( (amount > 0 && object.style.opacity < MAX_OPACITY) || (amount < 0 && object.style.opacity > MIN_OPACITY)) {
            var current = Number(object.style.opacity);
            var newopac = current + amount;
            object.style.opacity = String(newopac);
            setTimeout('animatefadein()', 25);
        }
    }
    animatefadein();
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FhZLQ/1/) is a working example.